# Samsung Galaxy A51 freezing and restarting after update

Tags: samsung, updates, screen, reboot

I updated my Samsung Galaxy A51 to Android 13 (One UI 5.1). My phone screen keeps freezing, going black, and restarting on its own. It happens every couple of minutes.

I did almost every possible way I searched online like hard reset and all settings reset. Memory is not full.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is it meant to be updated to Android 13 ?  Is this a normal Samsung update ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta updated to Android 13 and One UI 5.1.1